# WordPress Widgets Missings after Migration

Tags: wordpress, serialization, dbmigrate

I migrated my WordPress website from one server to another and also changed my domain name in the process.

I made the mistake of opening up my only copy of the database and doing a search and replace on it to change from the old domain to the new one.

Since some of the data is serialized in the database, my WordPress widgets disappeared after the migration.

Since I no longer have the untouched version of the database, is there anything I can do at this point?

I tried replacing the new domain with the old one hoping this will work, but the Widgets are still missing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try again for search and replace again by this software, it will do unserialize and replace and back to serialize as well.from this software:https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use widget Import Export plugin for it : https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-importer-exporter/